# Get Action Method original name if its decorate with ActionName MVC attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using action filter in my MVC code i have attached action filter with below mentioned action, but this action is decorate with MVC action name attribute.

But i want action method original name(ex. ChangeOrder) but i got in action filter name as a edit. I don't want to remove ActionName attribute.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[FormValueRequired("btnSaveOrderStatus")]
public ActionResult ChangeOrder(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Should i get Actionmethod original name without removing ActionName attribute.
please provide me way how to get original name not decorated name in mvc.

Comment: Why not use Edit (or ChangeOrder) everywhere?

Comment: @Div we have taking form collection from edit page. Please see question again i have update it.

Comment: @vatsal, So, you get `Edit` in `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the action method details corresponding to the `ActionName` by casting `filterContext.ActionDescriptor` to the [`ReflectedActionDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.reflectedactiondescriptor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the filter. This object has `MethodInfo` property which gives you all details of the method.

```
string actionMethodName = (filterContext.ActionDescriptor as ReflectedActionDescriptor)
            .MethodInfo
            .Name;
```

Comment: @vatsal Glad to help.